# Wordconv not working

Tags: ms-word, docx, doc

I have installed the compatibility pack for microsoft office. I understand it comes with a utility wordconv.exe which i could use to convert docx openxml formats to the old doc without word installed. Unfortunately when i try to run it as a command line program nothing happens (no error message no resulting files nothing). Searching the forums reveals there are other people experiencing the same issue but i haven't been able to find a way to fix it.

Is there anyone who might know what the problem is? (i have tried it on windows 7 on 2 different computers and win server 2008 and the problem is always there).

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else searching for a solution

I had the same issue using PowerShell. Switched to cmd.exe and the wordconv.exe tool works fine

i had to use the full path to wordconv.exe but relative path for input and output file was fine

```
“c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\wordconv.exe” -oice -nme .\file1.doc .\file1.docx
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, worked fine for converting Excel files with ExcelConv.exe but *some* Word docs would convert O.k. via Powershell and others just wouldn`t (but batch file worked fine). When I ran my Powershell script as an Admin user it happily converted all the Word docs I wanted.